# GDB: sync breakpoints with modified code

Tags: gdb

Some breakpoints are set during debugging, then saved with `save breakpoints bps`.
Code is modified by adding a few lines in the middle on the file.

When gdb is started again and `source bps` is done, those breakpoints, which are above first occurrence of code modification are ok, rest of them are relatively moved.

Is there a way to do some smart synchronization of breakpoints with modified file?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do some smart synchronization of breakpoints with
>   modified file?

This depends on how you are setting breakpoints. You can try to set them independently of line numbers, for example at function name:

```
(gdb) b main
```

This way breakpoint location is independent on line numbers and synchronizes automatically with modified file.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the breakpoints in the source code by doing [`int 3`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_%28x86_instruction%29#INT_3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define __DEBUG

#ifdef __DEBUG
#define __breakpoint__() __asm__ __volatile__("int $3\n")
#else
#define __breakpoint__()
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  const char *p = "Hello world!";

  __breakpoint__();
  printf("'%s'\n", p);

  return 0;
}
```